# Проблема при запуске Jar вне среды разработки

Tags: java, windows, javafx, netbeans, jar

Объясните пожалуйста нубу, в чем причина?

Есть IDE - NetBeans - где собственно и ведется разработка. Работаю с JavaFX + Maven; юзаю JFoenix.

В том то и проблема, что jar из-под NetBeans запускается без проблем. Если запускаю сам jar (с проводника, например) просто не открывается окно, процесс запускается (из диспетчера задач видно) и сразу закрывается без всяких ексепшенов.

Чисто логично понимаю что причина в внешней библиотеке т.к. без нее запускался (сам jar).

**Вопрос:** Как решить данную проблему? Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Просто соберите jar со всеми зависимостями. Например, как описано тут: https://www.mkyong.com/maven/create-a-fat-jar-file-maven-assembly-plugin/

Answer (score 1):

команда mvn install собирает jar файл проекта не внедряя в него зависимости, вероятно с этим и связана ваша ошибка.
Есть два решения. Впихать все в jar, как написал в комментариях @Alex Chermenin с помощью maven-assembly-plugin.

Второе решение собрать свой jar без зависимостей и указать в манифесте путь к библиотекам, например в подпапку lib:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>ХХХ</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                <mainClass>Droppy.Main</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>ХХХ</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>clean</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

В примере при вызове clean зависимости скопируются в папку lib на которую будет указатель в манифесте.

Comment: Во-первых, откуда уверенность, что автор использует maven? Во-вторых, команда mvn install не собирает jar, а устанавливает его в локальный репозиторий.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev про мавен в вопросе написано =) "Работаю с JavaFX + Maven"

Comment: Запустил clean install, в папке target появился мой jar, чяднт?