# Проблемы запуска проекта с Maven

Tags: java, maven, jar

Есть у меня проект, создал его в IDE, там же подключил библиотеки(guava и для записи CSV файлов), проект содержит ввод данных через args[ ]. Добавил начальные данные для компиляции(пути к файлам) - в IDE все работает, решил поставить проект на Maven, написал, подключил зависимости:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>groupId</groupId>
<artifactId>Java</artifactId>
<version>12</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>23.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>vasiuk.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>8</source>
                <target>8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Запустил его через командную строку, построился jar,
но при открытие jara в строке (java -jar Project.jar argumen1 argument2) возникли пробелы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
понимаю что сложно без всего проекта сказать, но что может быть причиной данных ошибок, заранее Спасибо.

Comment: Какие пробелы? Я не вижу пробелов

Comment: @AntonShchyrov не понял, пробелы?

Comment: Где у вас Guava в зависимостях?

Comment: @Russtam <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>23.0</version>
    </dependency>

Comment: @Russtam или я что-то не так подключил?

Comment: У вас мавен не включает зависимости в jar, посмотрите вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/816494/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B5-jar-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8B-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8/816593#816593

Comment: @Maxim Спасибо, понял в чем ошибка, буду исправлять.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Проблема при запуске Jar вне среды разработки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/816494/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b5-jar-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%8b-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы прописали `<addClasspath>true</addClasspath>`, что добавляет параметр `Class-Path` в файл `MANIFEST.MF`, внутри вашего jar файла, с перечислением jar файлов ваших зависимостей. Но в той директории, из которой вы его запускаете, jar файлов ваших зависимостей нет и, судя по вашему `pom.xml`, их нет даже в директории `target` вашего проекта. Поэтому загрузчик классов не находит классы ваших зависимостей. У вас есть два способа решить эту проблему:

**Способ 1:**

Скопировать jar файлы зависимостей в ту же дирекеторию, что и ваш jar файл или в директорию `lib` рядом с ним:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Поскольку в этом примере указана директория `lib`, её нужно добавить как префикс к перечисляемому в `Class-Path`. Для этого пропишите в настройках `<manifest>` вашего `maven-jar-plugin`:

```
<classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
```

Когда вы будете запускать ваш jar, вы должны находиться в той же директории, в которой находится директория `lib`. Например в директории `target`.

**Способ 2:**

Cобрать jar файл, который будет содержать классы всех зависимостей внутри себя:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

При этом у вас будут создаваться два jar файла: один как и раньше и другой со всеми классами внутри и с `jar-with-dependencies` в своём имени.

Comment: Спасибо, уже создал jar-with-dependencies.